# Customized color in a RichTextBox control - C#

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I have a function that appends text to a RichTextBox in a certain format, and then colors the message only. This is the function:

```
 internal void SendChat(Color color, string from, string message)
        {
            if (rtbChat.InvokeRequired)
            {
                rtbChat.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => SendChat(color, from, message)));
                return;
            }

            string Text = String.Format("[{0}] {1}: {2}", DateTime.Now.ToString("t"), from, message);
            rtbChat.AppendText(Text);
            rtbChat.Find(message);
            rtbChat.SelectionColor = color;

            rtbChat.AppendText("\r\n");

            rtbChat.ScrollToCaret();
        }
```

The output is like so:

```
[12:21 AM] Tester: Hello!
```

However, when I type a small sentence, such with 2 letters, sometimes the color doesn't appear, and sometimes it does. I fear it has to do with the Selection Color property.. is there a better way to do it or fix it?

Comment: Consider change the `from` variable name as it is a keyword. Just saying though

Comment: I tried it and it works fine. Although, when you post two same messages it colors only one of them, the first one in the rich text box. Is this your problem?

Comment: @OndrejJanacek It's a TCP Chat Client. It reads the message fine, but for some reason only long text gets colored. And small text like "a" doesn't. Here, tkae a look: http://puu.sh/4xoqo.png

Comment: @OndrejJanacek I found out the problem. It selects other text so the last text doesn't get colored. Is there another way rather than use "Find"? Because Find sometimes finds other stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Try to color the text as you add the message:

```
rtbChat.AppendText(string.Format("[{0}] {1}: ", DateTime.Now.ToString("t"), from));
rtbChat.SelectionColor = color;
rtbChat.AppendText(message);
rtbChat.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
rtbChat.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
rtbChat.ScrollToCaret();
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps;

```
    internal void SendChat(Color color, string from, string message)
    {
        if (rtbChat.InvokeRequired)
        {
            rtbChat.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => SendChat(color, from, message)));
            return;
        }

        string Text = String.Format("[{0}] {1}: {2}", DateTime.Now.ToString("t"), from, message);
        rtbChat.AppendText(Text);//Append text to rtbChat.
        //To speed up searching and highlighting text,its better to limit it to current line.
        int line = rtbChat.GetLineFromCharIndex(rtbChat.SelectionStart);//Get current line's number.
        string currenttext = rtbChat.Lines[line];//Get text of current line.
        Match match = Regex.Match(currenttext, message);//Find a match of the message in current text.
        if (match.Success)//If  message is found.
        {
            int position = rtbChat.SelectionStart;//Store caret's position before modifying it manually.
            rtbChat.Select(match.Index + rtbChat.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(line), match.Length);//Select the match.
            rtbChat.SelectionColor = color;//Apply color code.
            rtbChat.SelectionStart = position;//Restore caret's position.
        }
        rtbChat.Text += Environment.NewLine;//Append a new line after each operation.
    }
```

Well,to be honest this is something like syntax highlighting.But I hope it'll help you.